# How to parse android webview native crash log

Tags: android, android-webview, chromium, minidump

I was running a Vue webpage on an Android phone, and I got a native crash. The backtrace or log is as follows

```
2022-06-02 13:20:15.471 16788-16788/? A/crashpad: -----BEGIN CRASHPAD MINIDUMP-----
2022-06-02 13:20:15.471 16788-16788/? A/crashpad: )iyJD'cB_tSwO]?T?PW<4_wzS]wc6E(,qeUV*/f&18a8#Qu^dXq2S&apS>t)::c8Bg^i2_c>^-=jAFA=qX=:~eb2(m&VZq]IN4?-8w@9Dww3~F5L&DIr@u_ar\Pu6q>t*,/n{zA7sB^7u2on*n~F>oH))b5B/iz#>?"7gPieMCsXe<]=Wft;fsNBzI|.Be+<T7D?;AO$sa\M3NNpKaA)$X9[G<B@()w3Yf'/wpw-)bbC{/c)ODNRuQ1D95GDK<O<Ch;23QpPYwC-vr[26;}7/\YUgDDV.17r#LFMWOp\.UzDn'es$-=L4fs\u8&eQKgTyUKEy5093tbP-z5~sMzm2D;=5U}31;GFIopmM11VV{FU58Hc+xxc)GtTJFui~#6bA~&+Cot3~,hcEEn1VX`p(.Upj9Lh(7$dq+R<`1*u6HLcBeqB}'x8]4TA`W#2yi'3xKU"CV:9/udi/!*H;s<|Z^^Nebe/cn.ZrT*ZyD{MQ:P-,p<CuYEJ4jCJzaaB)Lpi
2022-06-02 13:20:15.471 16788-16788/? A/crashpad: ee>6z+1k1J[O6rkHG<9ZTBe)Dobz}c8T=s(z*)cmBN93V2$+r/&Z6[jlYwF$?]-0$qgc;`:nN)Co`d'%eb)geP>S!'(EV(\?Jx2z11A#co*dGv[2Z)*dM3uKhG}1&$5}vV^N^h]s5Q1C"p&U*6r[+@9JkF2|UbQk8>T7R/qa,?X.a3waz3L@bD}<fN6^oiebGW^U;Z-d!44][[7=V,y)~C=i)tV=zz]:UKR?<@|d5^N)gp=C'3k#1<w5_n@]y^NXX?n)O#a(1v4FxgF<Z,CxCvqFui$I&7KAu:_rog:~+{].waEfJ(f44%'k'nHY$7tK=CQ$rmL*f&t5p>b9ou+=R&gg7H#orcW_!JxArKb,8pH'"pXY"'zSCv5wk)Nr<vY2va.-,v'_P7&-'Lb]Mj8B`m&xIzOv+G8?'L+5mW}(Twc\[:Eu:qIesKU6kW2b}8sF_[Flk2DQD7)U}RuE)(]w?IR7^.waQV{MtK@"|*XKHo'tnvCUGJXtHkL;>Wh+;ekA
2022-06-02 13:20:15.471 16788-16788/? A/crashpad: Abvy/i;Dm/wa.oly~@J"M>>U@Sog64rPUnY;\_l:vv'6&R[SiB$u'tf\,'.aCvww*9CvQzON`4tQ$YJ&oW!5%Wy39[rfiMGB?a;KjRi6wz5h,vk3}o<-cw\RKLqVbl.?<_XJ2?j6;-cw*.vwzL+.^[<wGjxiJ.ucggs9t+~Ms7aK4EI+Guo;5C`a}IcRi6+{[k@p6<]zpw6xGB_ast?'vw/2c[UcZrJuhdDC5C&b~S+v4B%Uh^[rhUl?24Ab5\S~5TZa<$z/jds>~6"beg@3rO>6,%N3.iav-wY;S7vnmoxv$M(1a]Q.~O=NKLW)i3`[pq[DWtb#D>Z>hMoI7sX_&}DWtb]2q&yT4s$pPu6-51uijJ5[jdh-KBOY#7(Ezd;b1?pYh[1V8E97)@YfRjeW$sp6Sv_b,W9FEujYIeo5]kkW4Kt6%Ov}b2Ln:3{+<Dj+wgt[[,k\~Az~kJ)(V9;sLilW<W;,M=7el_&?VdRxOv#CQ<'L]6Q7F0'L~mw>.&DD
```

I wondered how I can parse this error into a human-readable backtrace format?

Comment: I don't use crashpad on Android but on Windows, it will generate a dmp file which can be debugged to find out why it crashed. There might be similar thing on Android too

Comment: Did you try using [`minidump`](https://openbase.com/js/minidump/documentation) to parse the crash dump in your Vue project? You will probably need to do that against the source code, since minidump requires symbolication.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Google team](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1269451#c7), there is no public tool for this

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32454384)

Comment: He did.  "There is no public tool for this".